# SendGrid API Returns "{List} does not exist"

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I'm trying to add an email address to a SendGrid list, which is the only list that exists on my account. I can retrieve the list successfully and send email, but I can't add emails to a contact list.

This is my approach (following the example on [Email API Reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Legacy_Features/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html) and authenticating following [Authentication API Reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/authentication.html)):

```
<?php
$API_KEY = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'); // Environment variable sourced correctly

$request_url =  "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json";
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY",
    "ContentType: application/json"
);
$data = array(
    "email" => "email@example.com",
    "name" => 'Stackoverflow'
);
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $sendgrid_user,
    'api_key'   => $sendgrid_pass,
    'list'      => "TestList",
    'data'      => json_encode($data)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($resp);
```

The output of the below code is:

```
{
    "error": "TestList does not exist"
}
```

I know *TestList* exists because I also tried [List all lists [GET]](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#List-All-Lists-GET) and that shows me this:

```
{
    "lists": [
        {
            "id": XXXXXX,
            "name": "TestList",
            "recipient_count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two different versions of the API. You're authenticating and GETting your lists via v3, but trying to add to v2.

In v3 recipients have a one-to-many relationship with lists, so you'll need to [create the recipient](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST), and then [add it to your list](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-a-Single-Recipient-to-a-List-POST)